# universal xpath for find the elements below

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find the th(by text) using the XPath. The problem is i need to define 3 xpath seprately to find the th by text as below:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

4)

[image]

Is it possible to have one universal xpath which finds the th by text?

Comment: Would this not work? `//th[text()="Primary NAIC"]`

Comment: only works for that one but  not for others. Because others are inside span and some of them are inside div

Comment: so how about `//th[*/text()="Primary NAIC"]`

Comment: No, this does not work at all

Comment: Last attempt: //th[text()='Primary NAIC' or .//*[text()='Primary NAIC']]

Comment: does no work for all of them

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking exactly? `//th` will return all attributes in the document. Update the question to clearly show what cases should match and what shouldn't and minimum piece of data needed.

Comment: I guess i can use this - //*[text()='text']

Answer (score 0):

was able to achieve this by using - //th//*[text()='Status']

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath will select every th node which contains a given text, or have some descendant node which contains the given text.

```
//th[descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(),'yourTextHere')]]
```